# Proper modifications of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a proper surjective holomorphic map between two $n$-dimensional connected complex manifolds $X$ and $Y$. $X$ is called a proper modification of $Y$ if there are nowhere dense compact analytic subsets $E\subset X$ and $S\subset Y$ such that the following hold:

(1) $f(E)\subset S$.
(2) $f$ maps $X\setminus E$ biholomorphically onto $Y\setminus S$.
(3) Every fibre $f^{-1}(y)$, $y\in S$, consists of more than one point.

Let $f:X\to\mathbb{C}^{n}$ be a proper modification of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$. Is $X$ necessarily an iterated blowup of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ at finitely many points?

Comment: I wonder what you call the Remmert reduction. If you take $M=X\times \mathbb{C}^n$, where $X$ is compact, isn't the Remmert reduction $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, you are correct. I edited my question.

Comment: do you want to say one/two lines about what is proper modification?? I hear the word **blowup** occasionally but did not hear **proper modification**.. Google search also does not say much...

Comment: Also it is better to make clear what do you mean by a blowup --- a blowup of a smooth subvariety, or a blowup of a sheaf of ideals.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I added the definition of proper modification. If things are still not clear, please let me know. I mean blowup at points.

Comment: What about blowing up $\Bbb{C}^n$ along a closed submanifold of positive dimension?

Comment: The exceptional set wouldn't be compact in that case. I guess equivalently one can ask if I contract a compact analytic subset of a manifold $M$ to get $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, then must $M$ be an iterated blowup of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ at finitely many points.

Comment: Oh, OK, sorry. I just missed the compactness hypothesis.

Comment: What if you blow up a point in $\mathbb C^n$ and then blow up a compact submanifold contained in the exceptional divisor of the first blow up?

Comment: Yes, I think that will do the job. Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A counterexample to your question is given by a blow-up at point in $\mathbb C^n$ followed by a blow-up along a compact submanifold contained in the exceptional divisor of the first blow-up.